# why am I getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java

I have created a simple program to practice polymorphism and inheritance, and it compiles and runs perfectly in a single file.  I then split the program into multiple files all in the same package. I was able to compile the files using `javac *.java`, and it compiled without errors.  However when I run the program by typing `java zoo_sim` i get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class zoo_sim Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: zoo_proj/zoo_sim (wrong name: zoo_sim)
```

The name of the class containing main is `zoo_sim`.
The name of the package is `zoo_proj`.

At the top of each file I have the line:

```
package zoo_proj;
```

I am new to java so I'm sorry if I'm missing something stupid here.
Thanks!

Edit: here is my `zoo_sim` class:

```
package zoo_proj;

public class zoo_sim {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
                //create and allocate animal array
                Animal animalArray[] = new Animal[3];

                //and Leo to animal array
                Animal Leo = new Cat("Leo", 4, 13);
                animalArray[0] = Leo;

                //add Crixus to animal array
                Animal Crixus = new Dog("Crixus", 5, 50);
                animalArray[1] = Crixus;

                //add Peter to animal array
                Animal Peter = new Pig("Peter", 3, 100);
                animalArray[2] = Peter;

                //c style for loop
                for(int i = 0; i < animalArray.length; i++) {
                        System.out.print(animalArray[i].getName() + " is " + animalArray[i].getAge() + " years old and says ");
                        animalArray[i].makeSound();
                }

                //print line in between
                System.out.println();

                //for each style for loop 
                for(Animal i : animalArray) {
                        System.out.print(i.getName() + " weighs " + i.getWeight() + " pounds and says ");
                        i.makeSound();
                }
        }
}
```

I'm using linux running in the command line. Here is my output for `java -version`:

```
openjdk version "11.0.3" 2019-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.3+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

when I type `java zoo_proj.zoo_sim` I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class zoo_proj.zoo_sim 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: zoo_proj.zoo_sim
```

Comment: Is there a main function defined in your class?

Comment: When compiling multiple .java files, you need to make sure to compile them all at the same time, not individually. I suggest using an IDE, that takes care of this (eclipse is free and used by many Java developers).

Comment: Try typing `java zoo_proj.zoo_sim` (from the directory above the `zoo_proj` directory) and tell us how you get on.

Comment: Please post your zoo_sim Class here

Comment: FYI: Java naming convention would be upper camel case for classes and lowercase for packages, e.g. zooproj.ZooSim (and your classes must match filenames).

Comment: Which java version are you using? Type the command `java -version` to find out. What platform are you on? Windows? Linux? MacOS? Something else?

Comment: Maybe you have implemented two public static void main() methods

Comment: There is only one main() method

Comment: Do you have a directory for your package `zoo_proj`. I.e. are all your classes in `zoo_proj` package within `zoo_proj` disk folder?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you're executing `java zoo_proj.zoo_sim` from within the package directory `zoo_proj`.
Go one level up and execute `java zoo_proj.zoo_sim` from the directory *one above* from `zoo_proj`.

My steps to reproduce are:

- Let my top directory be `/zoo`.
- All files of `package zoo_proj` are within `/zoo/zoo_proj` directory,
  i.e. the layout is:

```
/zoo
----/zoo_proj
-------------/Animal.java
-------------/Cat.java
-------------/Dog.java
-------------/Pig.java
-------------/zoo_sim.java
```

- All commands are executed while being in `/zoo` directory, NOT in `zoo/zoo_proj`.
- To compile java files, execute `javac zoo_proj/*.java`. On successful execution, `zoo_proj` should now contain corresponding `.class` file for each `.java` file.
- Execute `java zoo_proj.zoo_sim`. Program executes successfully.
- If you go to `/zoo/zoo_proj` and execute `java zoo_proj.zoo_sim` from here, the output is `Error: Could not find or load main class zoo_proj.zoo_sim`.